# how to format a string with same value for all placeholders

Tags: java

I have a template string

```java
str = "Hello %s, your name is %s, %s 's born in 1990."
```

I want to format this string, as below: `Hello Mr.P, your name is Mr.P, Mr.P 's born in 1990.` I can do the following below:

```java
String.format(str, "Mr.P","Mr.P","Mr.P");
```

to produce the above. Is there any other way to format the string without repeating same value `n` number of times as parameters

Answer (score 12):

You can simply reference a specific argument:

```
String.format("Hello %1$s, your name is %1$s", "Mr.P")
```

`%` = Start of format string

`1$` =   First argument

`s`     =   Type String

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: It appears that `String.format` is smarter than I thought. Do the positional syntax given by @Michael

Use `MessageFormat`.

```
import java.text.MessageFormat;
...
    String str = "Hello {0}, your name is {0}, {0}'s born in 1990.";
    String str2 = MessageFormat.format(str, "Mr. P");
    System.out.println(str2);
```

> Hello Mr. P, your name is Mr. P, Mr. Ps born in 1990.

This has the advantage of allowing you to create multiple placeholders and move them around in your pattern.

Docs: [MessageFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
str = str.replace("%s", "Mr.P");
```

Comment: Surely you mean `replaceAll()`.

Comment: replaceAll() and replace() will return same result in this case